# Open Street Maps app with offline maps

Tags: apps, maps

I am using an *HTC 7 Pro* and I am looking for an [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) app where I can download offline maps as **vector maps**.

I need OpenStreetMap because the maps are very good in my area of Argentina*.

Are there any apps that can provide this functionality?

### Edit

The only apps with offline maps I know ([SimpleOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_OSM) and [xMaps](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/XMaps)) do not provide offline vector maps.

<sub>* *Google Maps* is way too incomplete in my area of Argentina</sub>

Comment: Is not Google Maps good enough?

Comment: The maps are horrible for small cities of Argentina. Often there is only the city name without any streets cartographed.

Answer (score 2):

From http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Windows_Phone it appears that there are two apps for WP 7.x that will do cached OSM maps. Take a look and see if either one of them meets the need.

Comment: The Test Version of *Simple OSM* does not contain the possibility for downloading maps and I could not find any hint for that on the official site of the app. 
And *xMaps* is just bad.

Comment: well, I guess I don't have a good answer to that. You could risk the purchase of Simple OSM perhaps throwing money away, or live with the "just bad" xMaps.